# Couldn't access Wcf service hosted in a server through ajax call, but can access the same Wcf service hosted in local machine

Tags: wcf, rest

Created a Wcf Restful service and hosted in local Server. Another user is trying to consume the WCF Rest service from HTML5 page through ajax call.  However always it is throwing failure message

Configuration Settings:

1.The WCF Rest Service is hosted in http://jtl_109.com/mob/AppService.svc/GetUserAuthendication 
  2.Created a HTML5 Application and deployed it in another server. The URL is http://jtl_110.com/SampleApplication.html

> WCF Hosting Configuration Settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=ServerDatabase; Initial Catalog=NewDataBase; User ID=pras; Password=rita" />

  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <roleManager enabled="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="tSeyvaWCFEndPointBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="tSeyvaServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="AppServices.AppService" behaviorConfiguration="tSeyvaServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="tSeyvaWCFEndPointBehavior" 
                  bindingConfiguration="crossDomain" binding="webHttpBinding" 

        contract="AppServices.IAppService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

> And the ajax call is

```
        var data = { 'logindetails': { 'UserName': UN, 'Password': PW } };
        var st = JSON.stringify(data);
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://jtl_109/mob/AppService.svc/GetUserAuthendication",
            data: st,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                ServiceSucceeded(result);
                //// Play with response returned in JSON format
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR + "-" + textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
            }


        });
```

Can any one Please suggest how to consume the WCF Reset Service from another Site?

Comment: Where is your "server" ? Remote server?

Comment: Yep, it is a remote server.

Comment: My interrogation was leading to what @Brian said. Check below.

Comment: I have tried it and I'am getting page can't be displayed error

Comment: do u have any other idea...???

Comment: as @Brian suggested, figure out if there is a firewall blocking your connection to your service. You are either being blocked, or its not functioning as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the port on the server isn't being blocked by the firewall. An easy way to check is to simply type into your local machine's browser address bar the URL of the web service - http:/ /ServerName:8001/ServiceClass/ServiceMethod

If you get a 404 error or something like that, check the Firewall settings (inbound) to see that port is open. However, if you get a good response in your browser, then you know it's not the Firewall.

OK, so here's a very simple htm/JavaScript program I wrote as a test harness to ping a WCF web service.

```
 <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>     
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function Ping() {             
 //set up varable
 var sContent;
 sContent=  "<SoapXML><Your Content></XML>";

 var xmlhttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open('POST', Demo.URL.value, true);  

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4||xmlhttp.readyState == 0) {
    //alert("Ready state: " + xmlhttp.readyState.toString());
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        //alert("good");
        Demo.pingresponse.value = "Response: " +xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    if (xmlhttp.status !=200){
        //alert("bad");
        Demo.pingresponse.value = "Error: " +xmlhttp.status.toString() +"  response text:  " +xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
} else {
    //alert("readystate bad");
}
 }

    //send request    

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("POST http:localhost:8085/ServiceName  HTTP/1.1"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("VsDebuggerCausalityData","uI8ACQAA"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","\"http://SoapRequestHeader\""); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Host","localhost:8085"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Expect","100-continue"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection","Keep-Alive"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length","639");                   
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
xmlhttp.send(sContent);                  
 }

</script> 
</head> 
<body>     
<form name="Demo" action="" method="post">         
<div>
Web Service URL (i.e. http://ServerName:8085/ServiceName <br />
<input id="URL" type="text" size="140" value="http:/ /localhost:8085/ServiceName " />
<br />             
<input type="button" value="Ping" onclick="Ping();" /><br />
<textarea id="pingresponse"cols="100" rows="10">
</textarea> <br />     
</div>     
</form> 
</body> 
<html>
```

Obviously, this won't work for your site, but with some tweaks for the URL, Port and expected content, this might be a good starting point.

Comment: Hi, @brian.. thank u for u reply.. I have tried it both on internet explorer and chrome and i'am getting page can't be displayed error in both browsers

Comment: That suggests there's something wrong with the configuration of the web service. Also, make sure than when you start the web service that it's started 'as Administrator' so that you have rights to reserve the port.

Comment: OK, the client side of your config doesn't look quite right. Consuming a WCF service means http(s)://Server:port/Address, assuming you're using an HTTP protocol for communication. See my addition above for a very simple client side HTM/JavaScript program to connect to a WCF web service.